# How to select unique month-year combinations from SQLite database using OrmLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table with data and having a column with a date value.

```
Table A
table_id     date
```

So think of the table as to have more than thousands of rows and entries. What I want to do is to select all the distinct months and years from the table, so the output would probably look something like this:

```
09  2013  09-2013
12  2014  12-2014
01  2015  01-2015
03  2015  03-2015
05  2015  05-2015
```

Maybe something like this? If this is possible?

```
dao.queryBuilder().distinct().selectColumns("strftime('%mm-%yyyy', date)").query();
```

But I can't seem to make the above work the way I want it to. My model also uses the `DataType.DATE` on its `date` field.

Is there some way I can use the `distinct()` method of OrmLite to return this kind of list? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: do you have an IllegalArgumentException ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/23655/7/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(table_id INT, `date` DATE);

INSERT INTO TableA
VALUES (1, '2014-01-21'), (2, '2014-01-23'),
 (3, '2015-01-21'), (4, '2015-01-01'), (5, '2014-07-21'), (6, '2012-01-01');

SELECT DISTINCT
  STRFTIME('%m-%Y', t.`date`) AS Output
FROM TableA t
ORDER BY t.`date`;
```

I don't know `OrmLite` but I hope you manage to convert this solution or just use pure SQL with your ORM.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STRFTIME('%m', t.`date`) AS Month,
    STRFTIME('%Y', t.`date`) AS `Year`,
    STRFTIME('%m-%Y', t.`date`) AS Output
FROM TableA t
ORDER BY t.`date`;
```

Comment: I think I would need to use pure SQL so as to return genericrawresults. Is there a way to return the month and year integers and the pairing? I edited my question above

Answer (score 1):

To be sure we are talking about the same thing : ORMLite is a "Object Relational Mapping Lite (ORM Lite) provides some simple, lightweight functionality for persisting Java objects to SQL databases [...]."

It's not a just a wrapper to some SQL raw queries : it provides a way to create models (some POJO) that will be persisted in a database, without having to handle SQL constraints and strong knowledge. You will be able to store objects and retrieve them using plain Java objects.

The `selectColumns(String)` method take a column name as argument. You are passing a raw SQL statement.

If you read the source code of this method, you have this :

```
public QueryBuilder<T, ID> selectColumns(String... columns) {
    for (String column : columns) {
        addSelectColumnToList(column);
    }
    return this;
}
```

and then

```
private void addSelectColumnToList(String columnName) {
    verifyColumnName(columnName);
    addSelectToList(ColumnNameOrRawSql.withColumnName(columnName));
}
```

and to finish :

```
/**
 * Verify the columnName is valid and return its FieldType.
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if the column name is not valid.
 */
protected FieldType verifyColumnName(String columnName) {
    return tableInfo.getFieldTypeByColumnName(columnName);
}
```

So, with introspection, ORMLite will try to find the given column name in the fields of your model. Your string is clearly NOT a column name :)

Also, for a more "conceptual" concern : I think you should not convert the date format from your request. Actually, ORMLite is in charge to persist models in your database. He is not designed to format your data correctly for processing or display. If after persisting data in the DB you need to display it another, you will have to make the "parse stuff" at this moment, not before.

To be summarize :

- Use the real column name of the `date` field
- Continue to use `distinct()` the way you do it
- Parse the data to display it correctly if needed (let ORMLite choose the way it stores and load it)

**Sources**

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#QueryBuilder-Capabilities

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.java

https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/StatementBuilder.java